# How do I add use the make installed using homebrew instead of the macOS included make?

Tags: macos, terminal, gnu-make

I want to use the newer version of it (4.3) that I installed with homebrew, but my mac has 3.81 installed already and I can't remove it.

Comment: Why not just set your `PATH` to find the one you want first?

Comment: @MadScientist how would I change that?

Comment: Actually that's a crappy link.  Ugh who writes this stuff.  This one is better: https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux (even though it says Linux, it's the same process on MacOS)

Comment: @MadScientist I did `echo $PATH` and it said `/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin` I have an alias to the make I installed with homebrew inside of `/opt/homebrew/bin` but `make -v` still gives 3.81

Answer (score 1):

Read the [homebrew description](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/make) of GNU make:

> GNU "make" has been installed as "gmake".
> If you need to use it as "make", you can add a "gnubin" directory
> to your PATH from your bashrc like:
>
> ```
> PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/make/libexec/gnubin:$PATH"
> ```